# Как настроить Postfix + Яндекс.Почта для домена?

Tags: postfix, яндекс-почта

Настроил почту для домена через Яндекс. Если отправлять почту на info@romabox.ru с любого внешнего ящика (yandex, gmail), то все приходит нормально на аккаунт в Яндексе, но если отправлять почту с помощью скрипта на сервере, то она приходит на локальный ящик (который был создан ранее с таким же именем).

Если в Яндексе сделать новый ящик с другим именем и попробовать отправить на него почту с сервера, то в логах получаем следующее:

```
Jul  6 14:20:18 localhost postfix/pickup[4660]: A977321E84: uid=0 from=<root@localhost>
Jul  6 14:20:18 localhost postfix/cleanup[5221]: A977321E84: message-id=<20180706112018.A977321E84@mail.romabox.ru>
Jul  6 14:20:18 localhost opendkim[2232]: A977321E84: no signing table match for 'root@localhost.romabox.ru'
Jul  6 14:20:18 localhost postfix/qmgr[26745]: A977321E84: from=<root@localhost.romabox.ru>, size=399, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  6 14:20:18 localhost postfix/local[5223]: A977321E84: to=<hello@romabox.ru>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "hello")
Jul  6 14:20:18 localhost postfix/cleanup[5221]: B2FF721E85: message-id=<20180706112018.B2FF721E85@mail.romabox.ru>
Jul  6 14:20:18 localhost postfix/qmgr[26745]: B2FF721E85: from=<>, size=2173, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  6 14:20:18 localhost postfix/bounce[5224]: A977321E84: sender non-delivery notification: B2FF721E85
Jul  6 14:20:18 localhost postfix/qmgr[26745]: A977321E84: removed
Jul  6 14:20:18 localhost postfix/smtp[5226]: B2FF721E85: to=<root@localhost.romabox.ru>, relay=none, delay=0.06, delays=0.01/0.01/0.04/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not
Jul  6 14:20:18 localhost postfix/qmgr[26745]: B2FF721E85: removed
```

За отправку писем отвечает Postfix, как его настроить, чтобы он пересылал письма на Яндекс?

В /etc/postfix/main.cf сейчас следующее:

```
myhostname = mail.romabox.ru
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.romabox.ru, romabox.ru, localhost, localhost.localdomain
```

Comment: Судя по логам, ваш постфикс думает, что домен `romabox.ru` локальный, и пытается доставить почту локальному пользователю `hello`, которого не находит `(unknown user: "hello")`. Нужно "объяснить" постфиксу, что домен `romabox.ru` не его (см. в `main.cf` директивы `myhostname`, `mydomain`, `myorigin`), чтобы он в итоге отправлял сюда: `mx.yandex.net`

Comment: @de_frag а что точно там надо прописать?

Comment: там сейчас такие значения: myhostname = mail.romabox.ru
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.romabox.ru, romabox.ru, localhost, localhost.localdomain

Comment: давайте для начала из `mydestination` уберем `romabox.ru`. Рестарт постфикса и пробуйте снова отправить.

Comment: @de_frag спасибо за правильное направление поиска, проблема решилась, когда указал: mydestination = mx.yandex.net, localhost

Answer (score 0):

Отправка стала правильно работать, когда в /etc/postfix/main.cf указал следующее значение в поле mydestination:

```
mydestination = mx.yandex.net, localhost
```